# How to select mixed tags?

Tags: javascript

User wants to select randomly from the h1 tag then span tag then lists. How to highlight those also needs to give provision to make & clear highlight for the selection,so that he can export as document

Needs to highlight all the selected tags in range.

Comment: Better to provide the html structure in such cases. Community members will be able to help you out with solution that you will be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use maping elements, h1 tag and span , but for do this you need first data ,

if you dont have array data you can create new on in your javascaript code ,

after maping elements set function for clicking h1 and add class in your css `.userIsSelected` then use

in you javascript code into your function use

`element.classList.add("userIsSelected");`

i hope this help .